# How to change the image style used in a field in specific view results?

Tags: views, theming, 8

In Drupal 7 I used `hook_views_pre_render()` to update the image style for specific results. I'm trying to do the same for a view in Drupal 8 but I don't have the same options available in the field.

An example of the code I used before:
`$view->result[4]->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#image_style'] = 'image_style_name';`

There's no longer a 'rendered' array, just an ImageItem object with the target_id, title, width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that you can't use that approach anymore. Due to the performance improvements like [this one](https://www.drupal.org/node/1867518), fields are all rendered via `#pre_render` callbacks, and run through the same build process as normal entity rendering.

The good news is that `hook_entity_display_build_alter()` will run, the very same hook that runs for displaying an entity.

Views doesn't pass any additional context to this hook. Depending on how you were deciding which one to alter, you may still be able to accomplish this.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to accomplish the thing I wanted because I needed more context from views but thanks for the detailed explanation :)